# using ros map server with moveit

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, mobile-base, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question has been asked [at the moveit-users mailinglist by Troy Cordie](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/SoCKig7HoNM):

> I know this is a bit of an odd question considering most users are planning for armed platforms.

> I have a mobile base running in moveit and want to plan using a map in a similar fashion to move base. Is it possible to use the ros map server with moveit?

> or has anyone tried something similar? i.e. generate an environment for testing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272573/using-ros-map-server-with-moveit/) by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not directly.

MoveIt always works with 3D information.

The most straight-forward solution would be to generate an octomap from your 2d-map by projecting all occupied pixels to cuboids of some fixed height and use this octomap to plan.
You could implement a specialized [Octomap updater](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_ros/perception/pointcloud_octomap_updater_plugin_description.xml) to do that.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonka46](https://answers.ros.org/users/30744/tonka46/) on 2017-10-15**:
Cheers I ended up importing the bitmap into solid works and extruding it to give it depth then saving as an stl to import into moveit.